# How can i add "add to favorite" in flutter app, locally

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i'm pretty new, so i have an app with a grid view with articles, by clicking on any article it will navigate to the article page.
I want to add a favorite button to the article page, and by clicking on it, the article will be saved to a local page 'Favorite articles' that displays a grid view of favorite one's, so how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the ids of all favorite posts in a list, and save that list using something like SharedPrefreces, sqlite, hive, etc.